# Unknown Interaction on All interactions - Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

All of a sudden I keep on getting this error on most interactions and my bot just sends `"Bot is thinking...".

```js
[UnhandledRejection] DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/main/Desktop/Discordbots/gamerscavern/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/Users/main/Desktop/Discordbots/gamerscavern/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async SelectMenuInteraction.reply (/Users/main/Desktop/Discordbots/gamerscavern/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:98:5)
```

Example this help command. Which returns Unknown interaction on the `interaction.update()` part in the collector AND in the filter when another user interacts with it. I have no clue why this is happening. And as mentioned, it worked fine just a few hours ago.

Here is my code:

Help command:

```js
const {
    Client,
    Message,
    MessageEmbed,
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageSelectMenu,
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'List all of my commands or info about a specific command.',
    aliases: ['commands'],
    usage: '[command name]',
    category: 'info',
    cooldown: 3,
    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    execute: async (client, message, args, prefix) => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        const data = [];
        const { commands } = message.client;

        const emojis = {
            config: '⚙️',
            info: 'ℹ️',
            moderation: '',
            owner: '',
            utility: '',
            voice: '',
            welcoming: '',
        };

        if (!args[0]) {
            const directories = [
                ...new Set(client.commands.map((cmd) => cmd.category)),
            ].filter((e) => e !== 'secrets' && e !== undefined);

            const formatString = (str) =>
                `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`;

            const categories = directories.map((dir) => {
                const getCommands = client.commands
                    .filter((cmd) => cmd.category === dir)
                    .map((cmd) => {
                        return {
                            name: cmd.name || 'There is no name',
                            description:
                                cmd.description ||
                                'There is no description for this command',
                        };
                    });

                return {
                    directory: formatString(dir),
                    commands: getCommands,
                };
            });

            const initialEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Developer: Kev#1880')
                .setDescription(
                    '~~———————————————~~\n** Links ➼ ** [Invite](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=711371556504207423&permissions=8&scope=bot) | [Server](https://discord.gg/XkCTA88) | [Upvote](https://top.gg/bot/711371556504207423/vote)    \n~~———————————————~~\n\n**Please choose a category in the dropdown menu**'
                )
                .setColor('#5787E8')
                .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }))
                .setFooter(
                    `Requested by: ${message.author.tag}`,
                    message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
                )
                .setTimestamp();

            const components = (state) => [
                new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                    new MessageSelectMenu()
                        .setCustomId('help-menu')
                        .setPlaceholder('Please select a category')
                        .setDisabled(state)
                        .addOptions(
                            categories.map((cmd) => {
                                return {
                                    label: cmd.directory,
                                    value: cmd.directory.toLowerCase(),
                                    description: `Commands from ${cmd.directory} category`,
                                    emoji:
                                        emojis[cmd.directory.toLowerCase()] ||
                                        null,
                                };
                            })
                        )
                ),
            ];

            const initialMessage = await message.channel.send({
                embeds: [initialEmbed],
                components: components(false),
            });

            const filter = async (interaction) => {
                if (interaction.user.id === message.author.id) {
                    return true;
                }
                interaction.reply({
                    content: `This is not your help menu, create your own with >help!`,
                    ephemeral: true,
                });
                return false;
            };

            const collector = initialMessage.createMessageComponentCollector({
                filter,
                componentType: 'SELECT_MENU',
                time: 600000,
            });

            collector.on('collect', (interaction) => {
                console.log(interaction);
                const [directory] = interaction.values;
                const category = categories.find(
                    (x) => x.directory.toLowerCase() === directory
                );

                const categoryEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`${formatString(directory)} commands`)
                    .setDescription(
                        '~~———————————————~~\n** Links ➼ ** [Invite](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=711371556504207423&permissions=8&scope=bot) | [Server](https://discord.gg/XkCTA88) | [Upvote](https://top.gg/bot/711371556504207423/vote)    \n~~———————————————~~\n\n**Here are the list of commands**'
                    )
                    .setColor('#5787E8')
                    .addFields(
                        category.commands.map((cmd) => {
                            return {
                                name: `\`${cmd.name}\``,
                                value: cmd.description,
                                inline: true,
                            };
                        })
                    )
                    .setThumbnail(
                        client.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
                    )
                    .setFooter(
                        `Requested by: ${message.author.tag}`,
                        message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
                    )
                    .setTimestamp();

                interaction.update({
                    embeds: [categoryEmbed],
                });
            });

            collector.on('end', () => {
                const ranOut = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('RED')
                    .setTitle('Oops!')
                    .setDescription(
                        'Interaction ran out of time! Please create a new help menu!'
                    )
                    .setThumbnail(
                        client.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
                    )
                    .setFooter(
                        `Requested by: ${message.author.tag}`,
                        message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
                    )
                    .setTimestamp();

                initialMessage.edit({
                    embeds: [ranOut],
                    components: components(true),
                });
            });
        }
        if (args[0]) {
            const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
            const command =
                commands.get(name) ||
                commands.find((c) => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));
            if (!command) {
                return message.reply({
                    content: "that's not a valid command!",
                });
            }

            // data.push(`**Name:** ${command.name}`);

            if (command.aliases)
                data.push(`**Aliases:** ${command.aliases.join(', ')}`);
            if (command.description)
                data.push(`**Description:** ${command.description}`);
            if (command.nb) data.push(`**NB:** ${command.nb}`);
            if (command.userPermissions)
                data.push(
                    `**User Permissions:** \`${command.userPermissions.join(
                        ', '
                    )}\``
                );
            if (command.botPermissions)
                data.push(
                    `**Bot Permissions:** ${command.botPermissions
                        .map((perm) => {
                            return `\`${perm}\``;
                        })
                        .join(', ')}`
                );
            if (command.usage)
                data.push(
                    `**Usage:** \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``
                );
            if (command.examples)
                data.push(`**Examples:**
            ${command.examples
                .map((example) => {
                    return `\`${prefix}${command.name} ${example}\``;
                })
                .join('\n')}
        `);

            data.push(`**Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown || 3} second(s)`);

            const commandHelp = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Command: **${command.name}**`)
                .setColor('#5787E8')
                .setDescription(`${data.join('\n')}`)
                .setFooter(
                    `Requested by: ${message.author.tag}`,
                    message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
                );

            return message.reply({ embeds: [commandHelp] });
        }
    },
};
```

interactionCreate event:

```js
const blacklist = require('../../models/blacklists.js');
const guildBlacklist = require('../../models/guildBlacklist.js');
const reactionRoles = require('../../models/reactionRoles.js');
module.exports = async (Discord, client, interaction) => {
    //Slash Command Handling
    if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        // await interaction.deferReply();
        //blacklists
        const bl = await blacklist.findOne({ Client: client.user.id });
        if (bl) {
            if (bl.Users) {
                if (bl.Users.includes(interaction.user.id)) return;
            }
        }

        const gbl = await guildBlacklist.findOne({
            Guild: interaction.guild.id,
        });
        if (gbl) {
            if (gbl.Users) {
                if (gbl.Users.includes(interaction.user.id)) return;    
            }
        }

        const cmd = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (!cmd) return interaction.reply({ content: 'An error has occured' });

        const args = [];

        for (let option of interaction.options.data) {
            if (option.type === 'SUB_COMMAND') {
                if (option.name) args.push(option.name);
                option.options?.forEach((x) => {
                    if (x.value) args.push(x.value);
                });
            } else if (option.value) args.push(option.value);
        }
        interaction.member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(
            interaction.user.id
        );

        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(cmd.userPermissions || []))
            return interaction.reply({
                content: 'You do not have the permissions to use this command!',
                ephemeral: true,
            });

        cmd.execute(client, interaction, args);
    }

    //Context Menu Handling
    if (interaction.isContextMenu()) {
        await interaction.deferReply();
        const command = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (command) command.execute(client, interaction);
    }

    //Reaction Roles Handling
    if (interaction.isSelectMenu()) {
        await interaction.deferReply();
        const reactionPanel = await reactionRoles.findOne({
            guildId: interaction.guildId,
            'reactionPanels.customId': `${interaction.customId}`,
        });

        if (reactionPanel) {
            //if (interaction.customId !== 'reaction-roles') return;
            const roleId = interaction.values[0];

            const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId);
            if (!role) return;

            const memberRoles = interaction.member.roles;

            const hasRole = memberRoles.cache.has(roleId);

            if (hasRole) {
                memberRoles.remove(roleId);
                interaction.followUp({
                    content: `${role.name} has been removed from you`,
                    ephemeral: true,
                });
            } else {
                memberRoles.add(roleId);
                interaction.followUp({
                    content: `${role.name} has been added to you`,
                    ephemeral: true,
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What happened

---

If you do not reply or acknowledge the interaction in 3 seconds. There's a cooldown! 
The user will see interaction failed and the reply gate is closed.

## Solution

---

However, if you defer the reply and edit later, the gate will open until you update the defer or edit the reply.
Here's how to do it, and here's [the documentation about it](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply).

```js
interaction.deferReply();

// Do some stuff that takes time right here...

interaction.editReply({ content: "replied" });
```

---

To answer your other question about the bot sending `Bot is thinking...`,
It happens when you defer without editing the reply after.
 It will stay like that until you do something.